# not able to save file in files/myuploads folder in drupal 6

Tags: file-upload, drupal-6

I want to upload a file inside the **sites/default/files/myuploads** folder. But I am not able to. Actually I am not able to upload the file to any of the folder inside **sites/default/files/myuploads**.

Here is my code:

```
$validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('se', 'SE'));

$file = file_save_upload('fname',$validators, 'public://myuploads', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

if ($file) {
 $fid = $file->fid;
 $doc_url = file_create_url($file->uri);
 //Set the status of the uploaded file.
 $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

//other code...
}
```

The upload will work fine if I just give **public://**. So it will be in the **sites/default/files** folder. And when I print the $file, in that the **["destination"]** => "**sites/default/files/./test.se**"

How can I do this? Any idea how I can upload into the myuploads folder ?

Answer (score 0):

- Verify the write permission for "myuploads" folders.
- Change the $validators variable like this:

  $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('se SE'));